# python3 opencv is not saving readable video

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, opencv, html5-video

I just want make the video to be web browser compatible.  From the video objects I'm getting the image path, the image is png type I just want to convert those images to video and show it in the browser.

```
    path = settings.WEBUI_ROOT + '/events/'
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    video = Video.objects.get(id=video_id)
    movements = Image.objects.filter(video=video)

    frame = cv2.imread(movements[0].file_path, 1)
    height, width, channel = frame.shape
    video_name = 'eventvideo.mp4'
    output_video = cv2.VideoWriter(path + video_name, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V'), 15, (height, width))

    for _, image in enumerate(movements):
        image = Image.objects.get(id=image.id)
        frame = cv2.imread(image.file_path)
        output_video.write(frame)
    output_video.release()

    result = {
        'success': True,
        'path': "events/" + event_video_name
    }
    return JsonResponse(result, safe=False)
```

Tools used Django and JS

Comment: Come on guys help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the VideoWriter, you should use a `(width, height)` tuple for the frame size, not `(height, width)`.

Comment: Ya changed the same but browser is not supporting the video codec.

Comment: OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x34363248/'H264' is not supported with codec id 27 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x31637661/'avc1'
[h264_nvenc @ 0x7f4e0407f5e0] Cannot load libcuda.so.1
Could not open codec 'h264_nvenc': Unspecified error

Comment: @Karthikaeyan well, the error is self explanatory - OpenCV is trying to load NVIDIA NVENC codec and fails (you do not have CUDA installed). Do you even have an NVIDIA GPU installed? Can you get an OpenCV build that has FFmpeg with x264 built in?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis I don't have Nvidia GPU, mine is AMD and I tried this https://gist.github.com/yjxiong/d716c857258f0295b58d148fbf8c489d  steps and getting the same error and between I'm workinig in ubuntu

Comment: And I tried webm I'm getting this error, except these two formats all other working properly, I just need to display the video on web browser.          
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x30385056/'VP80' is not supported with codec id 139 and format 'webm / WebM'

Comment: Not sure where exactly the issue is. You should create a new question, listing your OS version, OpenCV source version you installed, ffmpeg version and CUDA installation information to get some help on it.

Comment: @Karthikaeyan I'm not sure how OpenCV works, if it has FFmpeg linked in statically or uses the one on system, but can you try `avconv -codecs` or `ffmpeg -codecs` to see what codecs you have?